# ionic 4 - trying to make url sanitizer work

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Im working on Ionic 4 with Angular 7.2.2 and trying to sanitize an URL to use it in an iFrame.

I'm trying this way:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

private sanitizer:DomSanitizer,

...

console.log(i.url);
let newUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(i.url);
```

So the first console.log() shows original URL and then browser errors:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'sanitizer' of undefined
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'sanitizer' of undefined

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

well you are getting that error because you should not console.log the sanitizer you should give us more details about what are you trying to do with the url but the way you are calling it is correct actually if you use the var newurl it will work you wont get cross sites errors.

in this video the autor if using it in the propper way maybe it could help you

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JeKfQ2r2r8